# Is the installation of Xcode from App Store enough for having the developer tools?

Tags: macos, xcode

today I tried to install the new version of Xcode.
Before that I removed the developer tools with the following command:

```
sudo /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

I also had other folder in `/Library/Developer` such as 4.2 4.2.1 ...

After that I installed the new Xcode and I noticed that the folder `/Library/Developer` contains only the `Shared` folder, which doesn't contain the command `uninstall-devtools`.

Did I install the developer tools or do I have to do something more?

Another related problem is that when I try to install Flann through Homebrew it reports the following error:

> xcode-select: Error: No Xcode folder is set. Run `xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>` to set the path to the Xcode folder.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think XCode is now installed under /Developer

Comment: I don't have the folder /Developer... Don't know why!

Comment: @Jason with the update in 4.3, Xcode now installs into /Applications, no longer uses the /Developer folders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing Xcode 4.3 does install the developer tools, but not for command line access. With this version, everything has been moved into the application bundle, which means there is no need for a uninstaller, since you can just delete the application. If you want to install the command line tools, open Xcode and go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads, select the Components tab, and click the button next to Command Line Tools. (This might add an uninstaller somewhere, but I'm not sure.)

As for Homebrew, you might have to wait for an update before it supports Xcode 4.3, since everything was moved. I would suggest trying `/Applications/Xcode.app` as the `<xcode_folder_path>`, since most of the hierarchy appears to be the same.

The homebrew developers are tracking these changes in their bug database so, you may want to [monitor this thread for workarounds and notification](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9179) of when the homebrew system will effortlessly work with the new changes for Xcode 4.3.

Comment: So in you opinion if I have already installed XCode and the Command Line Tools then am I in the same situation of this morning? :D (Of course with a newer version of the dev tools).

Comment: If you type `man xcode-select` you will discover that the right path is /Applications/Xcode.app/

Comment: @lucaghera OK, thanks. I was just guessing that it wanted the Developer folder. I'll fix my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is providing these command line developer tools as a stand alone package now, so you may wish to get a free developer account if you don't want to [wait for homebrew to change and locate / link to the new directory structure](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9179).

A nice summary of the state of affairs on Xcode 4.3.x and older as well as the upcoming changes and benefits of having the command line tools packaged by Apple officially with headers is [on Kenneth Reitz's blog](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html).

Answer (score 1):

`xcode-select -select "/Applications/Xcode.app"` fixed this problem for me.  Everything is peachy now.

Answer (score 0):

When you download Xcode from the App Store, you're actually downloading an app called Install Xcode. You need to run that if you haven't; I'm not clear on whether or not you performed this step. Once you do that, you will have

```
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
```

and other components (assuming you install to the default location), but look for Xcode.app first.

Comment: This has changed with the release of Xcode 4.3 which installs in /Applications as any other application. /Developer is not used any longer and Xcode 4.3 offers to delete it when starting for the first time.

Comment: Xcode 4.3 is actually the root cause for all these Xcode related questions today.